# Verify value in a PHP array and reasign result to the variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I would be much grateful if you could help in solving this PHP issue.

1. I needs to verify the value of `$fl_blackriver`, `$fl_flacq`, etc...
2. if `value==""`, assign `0` to this value
3. update the corresponding variable with the updated value

```
$fl_blackriver = $_REQUEST['fl_blackriver'];
$fl_flacq = $_REQUEST['fl_flacq'];
$fl_grandport = $_REQUEST['fl_grandport'];
$fl_moka = $_REQUEST['fl_moka'];
$fl_pamplemousses = $_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses'];
$fl_plaineswilhems = $_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems'];
$fl_portlouis = $_REQUEST['fl_portlouis'];
$fl_rivieredurempart = $_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart'];
$fl_savanne = $_REQUEST['fl_savanne'];
$fl_finalize = $_REQUEST['fl_finalize'];

$district = array($fl_blackriver,$fl_flacq,$fl_grandport,$fl_moka,$fl_pamplemousses,$fl_plaineswilhems,$fl_portlouis,$fl_rivieredurempart,$fl_savanne,$fl_finalize);

$arrlength = count($district);


for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
{
  if ($district[$x]=="")
    $district[$x] = "0";
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the current code

Comment: Assigning the updated value to the same variable is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look nice but it should do the trick:

```
$fl_blackriver = $_REQUEST['fl_blackriver'];
$fl_flacq = $_REQUEST['fl_flacq'];
$fl_grandport = $_REQUEST['fl_grandport'];
$fl_moka = $_REQUEST['fl_moka'];
$fl_pamplemousses = $_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses'];
$fl_plaineswilhems = $_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems'];
$fl_portlouis = $_REQUEST['fl_portlouis'];
$fl_rivieredurempart = $_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart'];
$fl_savanne = $_REQUEST['fl_savanne'];
$fl_finalize = $_REQUEST['fl_finalize'];

$district = array(
    'fl_blackriver' => $fl_blackriver,
    'fl_flacq' => $fl_flacq,
    'fl_grandport' => $fl_grandport,
    'fl_moka' => $fl_moka,
    'fl_pamplemousses' => $fl_pamplemousses,
    'fl_plaineswilhems' => $fl_plaineswilhems,
    'fl_portlouis' => $fl_portlouis,
    'fl_rivieredurempart' => $fl_rivieredurempart,
    'fl_savanne' => $fl_savanne,
    'fl_finalize' => $fl_finalize
);

foreach ($district as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === "") {
        $$key = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks luka. Thats what i was looking for.

Just a minor change i brought:
if ($value == "") instead of if ($value ==="") work much better, as it take the value of checkbox into consideration too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ternary operator like this,

```
$fl_blackriver = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_blackriver']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_blackriver'] : 0 ;    
        $fl_flacq = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_flacq']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_flacq'] : 0 ;  
        $fl_grandport = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_grandport']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_grandport'] : 0 ;    
        $fl_moka = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_moka']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_moka'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_pamplemousses = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_plaineswilhems = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_portlouis = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_portlouis']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_portlouis'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_rivieredurempart = !empty($_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_savanne =  !empty($_REQUEST['fl_savanne']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_savanne'] : 0 ; 
        $fl_finalize =  !empty($_REQUEST['fl_finalize']) ? $_REQUEST['fl_finalize'] : 0 ;
```

Comment: Be careful when using `empty()` since it will return `false` in more cases than just being an empty string.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use array to do the same. make it more easier, with less code

Comment: If you have a fixed number of elements in the $_REQUEST they why should go for a loop. Using loops and ifs include more code and it does not make it look easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following process. It will check the value whether it is empty or not. If the value is empty then it will set the value to 0. Otherwise it will take the requested value.

```
$fl_blackriver = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_blackriver'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_blackriver'] : 0;
$fl_flacq = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_flacq'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_flacq'] : 0;
$fl_grandport = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_grandport'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_grandport'] : 0;
$fl_moka = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_moka'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_moka'] : 0;
$fl_pamplemousses = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_pamplemousses'] : 0;
$fl_plaineswilhems = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_plaineswilhems'] : 0;
$fl_portlouis = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_portlouis'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_portlouis'] : 0;
$fl_rivieredurempart = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_rivieredurempart'] : 0;
$fl_savanne = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_savanne'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_savanne'] : 0;
$fl_finalize = (isset($_REQUEST['fl_finalize'])) ? $_REQUEST['fl_finalize'] : 0;

$district = array($fl_blackriver,$fl_flacq,$fl_grandport,$fl_moka,$fl_pamplemousses,$fl_plaineswilhems,$fl_portlouis,$fl_rivieredurempart,$fl_savanne,$fl_finalize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
if (! is_numeric($value)) {
    $_REQUEST[$key] = 0;
}}
extract($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in a variadic function returning an array when multiple arguments are given or source of any type when only one argument is present.

```
function request(string ...$names)
{
  foreach ($names as &$v)
    $v = '' === ($v = $_REQUEST[$v] ?? 0) ? 0 : $v;
  return 1 === count($names) ? $names[0] : $names;
}


[$fl_blackriver, $fl_flacq] = request('fl_blackriver', 'fl_flacq');
$fl_grandport               = request('fl_grandport');

$district                   = request('fl_blackriver','fl_flacq','fl_grandport','fl_moka','fl_pamplemousses','fl_plaineswilhems','fl_portlouis','fl_rivieredurempart','fl_savanne','fl_finalize');

var_dump($fl_blackriver, $fl_flacq, $fl_grandport);
var_dump($district);
```

To get key/value pairs in an associative array:

```
function request_assoc(string ...$names) : array
{
  $names = array_flip($names);
  foreach ($names as $k => &$v)
    $v = '' === ($v = $_REQUEST[$k] ?? 0) ? 0 : $v;

  return $names;
}
```